# why in JavaScript's: obj = new Boolean(false) , (obj && true) is true, and (obj || false) is false?

Tags: javascript

To see the result, open console in Google Chrome, do the following:

```
obj = new Boolean(false)
"obj && true: " + (obj && true)
"obj || true: " + (obj || false)
```

and:

```
(obj && true) == true   // this is true
(obj || false) == true   // this is false
```

and why

```
(obj || false)
```

returns the Boolean object, instead of a boolean value?

(hmm.. I also put a summary as answer below)

Comment: I bet "false" in the last line refers to `obj`. Try `obj || 0`

Comment: I see the false object presented to me as `Boolean {}`

Comment: I don't get what you report. In particular, `(obj || false)` returns `Boolean {}`. It tests as a truthy value: `!!(obj || false)` is `true`. Note that `'false'` is not the same thing as `false`!

Comment: now you're seeing false because that's how `new Boolean(false)` converts to string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two concepts which need to be considered here:

```
obj = new Boolean(false)
```

creates an Object, whose values is `false`. The Object itself is considered truthy, it's value (which you get with `toString()` or `valueOf()`) of course is the boolean value `false`.

```
(x||y)
```

returns the first truthy value (or if none are present, the last falsy value) and

```
(x&&y)
```

returns the first falsy value (or if none are present, the last truthy value).

So `(obj||false)` returns your *Boolean Object*, `(obj&&true)` returns the second (`true`) value.

The further preceeding depends on the context of your expression.

```
"obj && true: " + (obj && true)
```

demands a string context, so `toString()` is called on your Boolean Object, returning it's value which is `false` (While the object itself is truthy!).

Furthermore,

`(obj && true) == true` compares `true == true` which of course is true. However,

`(obj || true) == true` does a lot of type coercion [§11.9.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) and compares

`ToPrimitive(obj) == ToNumber(true)` ([§9.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.1) and [§9.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3)) which results in `NaN == 1` which yields false.

The results get more predictable if you use the strict equality operator [§11.9.6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6).

Answer (score 2):

For the first case, the `obj` is a truthy value so true && true returns true.

For the second case, it returns obj which is `Boolean{}`. If you then cast it to String (which happens, if you do `"string" + (obj || false)`), then it will return its *value*, which is "false".

Again, this is because the *value* of `obj` is `false` but the Object itself is a `truthy` value!

Comment: Thx for the reply. Why does (obj || false) return a Boolean object instead of a boolean value?

Comment: Because obj *is* a Boolean object, because you created it like that. If you want it otherwise, you should convert obj to a primitive boolean like 'obj = !!obj;' or have created obj as 'obj = false;' to start with.

Comment: IC. so the || operator is actually short-cast operator to return the first non-false value it sees. Thx a lot ;)

Comment: Completely correct! Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example your `obj` is evaluated as truthy and hence `truthy && true == true`.

In the second example, while evaluating the object is is again considered truthy and so the lazy evaluation stops after evaluating `obj`. Then `obj` is returned, which itself yields a value of `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Your object (obj) is a wrapped boolean, and JavaScript treats it that way.

(new Boolan(false) || false) is false indeed.

Answer (score 0):

my Chrome browser returns true for the former statement
and returns a Boolean Object for the latter statement

Answer (score 0):

After getting the answers below, let me do a summary here(People on StackOverFlow are really helpful~ Thank you all~):

The short-cut behavior of && and || operator, and the true value of object, is the root of the problem here I guess.

(the below are what I summarized from several behaviors I tried)

I would use:

```
o = new Object;
t = new Boolean(true);
f = new Boolean(false);
```

When || is used, it would take the first non-false value. Because:

```
(f || t) == true; // false
(t || f) == true; // true
(false || f) == true; // false
typeof (false || f);  // "object"
typeof (true || f);   // "boolean"
```

When && is used, it would take the first non-true value. Since objects are by-nature to be true, it would try to return the last occurring object, or the first false if there's.

Here's an example:

```
(o || t) // it returns the 'o' since it's the first true
(o && t) // it returns t since it's the last true
(true && t) // it returns t also, same reason
(false && t) // it returns false since it's the first occurring false.
```